# Dragging external events onto fullcalendar and save them in to database with json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, fullcalendar

This example: http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.3/demos/external-dragging.html

But how can i save the external div data in to my database with json.

Answer (score 3):

You can `listen` drag&drop events in fullcalendar and do any actions. Something like this:

```
var events = []; //array of events in json format
var calendar = $('#calendar-container').fullCalendar({
theme: true,
header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
    console.log('create new event');
},
editable: true,
droppable: true,
events: events,
eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
    console.log('move exists event');
    saveEvent(event);
},
loading: function(bool) {},
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    console.log('edit exists event');
}
});

function saveEvent(event){
   $.ajax({
       url: 'save_event.php',
       type: 'post',
       data: {event: event},
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(response){
          console.log('response');
       }
  });
}
```

When you move event `fullCalendar.eventDrop()` will be called.
You can see all event functions in [plugin docs](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/)